# Image uploading to Azure blob storage

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using Angular 2 for the frontend and Node.js for the backend. I am trying to upload a file to Azure storage blob container but keep getting an error when trying to send the image to api. Any help will be appreciated thanks.

This is the error on the server side:

```
contentType: files.myfile.type,

TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

The error on client side

```
core.js:1521 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
error
:
ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers
:
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message
:
"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
0
statusText
:
"Unknown Error"
url
:
null
__proto__
:
HttpResponseBase
```

upload.component.ts

```
    export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {
selectedFile: File = null;

  onFileSelected(event) {
this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
  }

  onUpload() {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/upload', fd , {
    reportProgress : true,
    observe: 'events'
     }).subscribe( event => {
console.log(event);
    });

  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }



}
```

server.js

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        var options = {
                contentType: files.myfile.type,
                metadata: { fileName: files.myfile.name }
        };
        blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('images', files.myfile.name, files.myfile.path, options, function(error, result, response) {
            if(!error){
            // file uploaded
                res.send('file uploaded!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post how does files JSON look like

Comment: Hello i am really new to working with JSON. Can you guide me towards how I would do that ?

Comment: just put console.log(JSON.stringify(files)) and post here

Comment: all I get is {"isTrusted":true}
i put  onFileSelected(event) {
this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
console.log(JSON.stringify(event));


  }

Comment: which means file is not being passed

Comment: I see so the problem is when selecting the file. Thank you

Comment: can you mark the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see the object File which you are passing to the server is null, so it throws the above error.

You could check the issue on the network tab on chrome developer tools and see if your file is being selected. Hope it helps.

Comment: here is the json file that gets send to the server {"image":{"size":85814,"path":"/var/folders/w8/99gp0wl979n6r6wrc6kynjym0000gn/T/upload_7dbf37d7abc878d2ff1e8f4635de7850","name":"Screen Shot 2018-07-08 at 2.35.04 AM.png","type":"image/png","mtime":"2018-07-10T22:34:34.654Z"}}

Comment: so this is the file object?

Comment: Yes I got it working. The mistake was in the node.js file